# Finding certain strings with grep (or similar)

Tags: command-line, grep

I have two parts of a string that I know, called `phrase1` and `phrase2` that are in the same line of a file that occur multiple times throughout the file. I need to extract these lines from the file; however, there are numbers in between that I do not know and the lines can vary. For instance, there are lines that may look like:

```
phrase1 654654 phrase2
phrase1 22 phrase2
phrase1 949 phrase2

etc.
```

However, I do know that I can write a code specifically for a particular line. For instance, I can write for line 2 above the following to find it:

```bsh
grep "phrase1 [0-9][0-9] phrase2" file
```

What code can I write using grep (or similar) in order to extract all the lines containing both `phrase1` and `phrase2` without knowing the numbers, or anything else for that matter, in between?

Answer (score 2):

Two methods: with regular expressions:

```
grep "phrase1 .* phrase2" file
```

This search for phrase1, one space, a string of characters that could be whatever you want, another space, and the phrase2, anywhere in the line (it matches lines that have more material before "phrase1" and after "phrase2")

If the two phrases have to be at the start and end of the line, see @AndreasT answer: you can use `^` and `$` to "anchor" the regular expression at the start and end of the line.

If you want to match just numbers between the two phrases, the answer by minerz029 is the correct one; "[0-9]+" matches a repetition of digit ("+" means "a sequence of at least one character").

If you want just numbers *and* phrase1 and phrase2 must be at the start and end of the phrase, combine the twos:

```
grep "^phrase1 [0-9]+ phrase2$" file
```

Or the "trick"/hack...

```
grep "phrase1" file | grep "phrase2"
```

Explication: the first command search for all the occurences of phrase1, then "pipes" the resulting lines as input to the second grep, that outputs all the lines that matches phrase2.

However, as noticed by @AndreasT, this second method matches the reversed "phrase2...phrase1" pattern, which could be unwanted.

Comment: Your second "trick" would match also the line `phrase2 ... phrase1`.

Comment: ?? Both your first method and mine match `phrase1...phrase2` but **not** `phrase2...phrase1`, as instead your second does.

Answer (score 2):

If the lines you are looking for *start* with `phrase1` and *end* with `phrase2`, then I would suggest

```
grep "^phrase1.*phrase2$"
```

Here is a list of the special characters used

- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `$` matches the end of a line
- `.` matches every character
- `*` matches 0 or more occurrences of the previous character

So, basically, `grep` looks for lines beginning with `phrase1`, followed by 0 or more characters and ending with `phrase2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to detect only digits in between the phrases:

```
grep -E '^phrase1 [0-9]+ phrase2$'
```

The `-E` option uses "Extended regular expressions", adding support for the `+` operator.

Breakdown:

- `^` means to match the start of the line.
- `+` after the `[0-9]` means to search for one or more occurrences of the preceding expression, which in this case is the class `[0-9]`.
- `$` means to match the end of the line.